# Flask and sqlalchemy: Get uploaded file using path stored on database

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I'm using flask and sqlalchemy and I'm having issues regarding file uploading.

I'm uploading the file with a form and storing the URL to the DB, so I can display it inside  on the page.

Here's the form's code:

```
        boxart = request.files['boxart']

        if boxart:
            filename = secure_filename(boxart.filename)
            boxart_path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']+"boxart/", filename)
            boxart.save(boxart_path)
            game_son.boxart = boxart_path

        db.session.add(game_son)
        db.session.commit()
```

So I go to my template and I can print the content of game_son.boxart and there is the full path to the file. If I click on the link, I can access, but the image will not display inside  tag...

I tried getting it on the template by using:

```
    <img src="{{ game_son.boxart_url() }}" />
```

Inside the model, I defined a boxart_url method, in case I need to parse the string before sending it

```
  class Game_son(db.Model):
    __searchable__ = ['version_name']
    son_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    version_name = db.Column(db.String(128), index=True, unique=False)
    son_timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    dad = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('game_dad.id'))
    console = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('platform.id'))
    boxart = db.Column(db.String(256))
    thumbnail = db.Column(db.String(256))
    genre = db.Column(db.String(32))
    subgenre = db.Column(db.String(32))

    def boxart_url(self):
        return self.boxart 

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Game %r>: %r' % (self.version_name, self.dad)
```

The page's view just send the entire object (game) to the page.

The url that is arriving on the page is:

/home/removed_my_pc_user/app/media/boxart/image.jpg

**Edit:**
I just remembered that I'm using a virtual environment on the project.

Is it related to chmod?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Where is your code that displays the image in your template? How are you getting the data back from the database? You've provided the insert statement, but this doesn't help us resolve your issue with it not showing in the image tag.

Comment: Thank you. I added more information in the question. If there is something else, just tell me.

Comment: When you view source, what is the src for your img tag?

Comment: <img src="/home/removed_my_user/app/media/boxart/image.jpg">

Comment: So, when you view the image and it works, the url will be something like this? http://127.0.0.1:1234/home/removed_my_user/app/media/boxart/image.jpg

Comment: It seems that I can't access the file using the ip/path like your example. I was opening the file only with the path, ignoring the ip... My mistake. Do I need to create a route or something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, It's strange but I will answer my own question.

The solution is simple, I chose to store only the file names inside the database.

Then I created a route to a view that will return the file using the `send_from_directory` function from `flask.ext.uploads`

```
@app.route('/boxart/<filename>')
    def uploaded_boxart(filename):
        return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],filename)
```

So, inside the template we can use the `url_for()` function to load the file, sending as a parameter the filename stored inside the database.

```
<img src="{{ url_for('uploaded_boxart', filename = game_son.boxart)}}" />
```

Also, I think that one of my mistakes was putting the **media/** folder inside the **app/** folder, and not inside the root directory. So I also reconfigured the `UPLOAD_FOLDER` in app.config.